# App.xaml.cs will run again unexpectedly in Debug mode

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-debugging, android-wifi

I am using the APP to connect to a device in Xamarin debug mode.

When the system is trying to connect to the device(like the screenshot shows "Connecting to device..."), if I press the back button to home(desktop) and back to APP, I find that the code will run `App.xaml.cs` again, so I will see the screen will show `Example_A_Page` again and then show `Example_B_Page` afterward.

Then I tried again without the debug mode this time.
When I press the back button to home(desktop) and then back to APP, APP is still running `Example_B_Page`.

Does anybody know why this situation happened?

Here is the pseudo code

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Example_A_Page());
    }
}

public partial class Example_A_Page : ContentPage
{
    public Example_A_Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new Example_B_Page());
    }
}

public partial class Example_B_Page : ContentPage
{
    public Example_B_Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do the connection behavior...
        //Connected to the device...
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `OnAppearing()` is executed everytime the page becomes visible. This is the case when it first gets created but also when the page gets hidden and then becomes visible again. That's also what the name implies. You should move the code that opens the popup page somewhere else. E.g. into an event handler.

Comment: Did that mean the App restarted when press to Home? You could add some debug info to track the Application states in this process. That might be helpful.